# How to find the last digit of a number in base b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, power-towers

For a number $a^{x^{...^n}} $. To find its last digit in a base b,

Imagine that I have this number $a^{x^{y}}$ to simplify the problem. Then I calculate  $a^{x} \equiv c \pmod b$  and after that $c^{y} \equiv d \pmod b$ which means that d is the last digit. Am i right?

Thanks !

Comment: Be careful!  Exponentiation is not associative.  The order of operations you propose disagrees with the conventional understanding.  Perhaps an easy example will help you see the point.

Comment: Oh I see!  I didn't think about that. Then, I should solve $x^y \equiv c \pmod b$ first and $a^c \equiv \pmod b$. Right?

Comment: @hardmath but for  $a^{x^{...^n}}$ is there a general method?

Comment: Yes, if you know [Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/eulerthm.pdf), you can take the "tower of exponents" down one by one.  But one works from the top of the tower downward, not from the base upward as you were trying to do.  Again, a smallish example should show you how to proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: While that would clearly form a subproblem to this Question, the issue of how to deal with a *tower* of exponents seems especially important here.

Comment: it's the same basic method, unless you want to also find quotients...

Answer (score 1):

The procedure you suggest does not work since the conventional meaning of $a^{x^{y}}$ is that it means $a^{(x^{y})}$ whereas you were finding $(a^x)^{y}$.

Depending on the problem you wish to solve, it is likely that the best method for you would be to find a power $N$ of $a$ which is 1 modulo $b$ and then consider $x^y$ modulo $N$.

Comment: $2^{(2^{3})}=256$ whereas $(2^2)^{3}=64$. They do not have the same last digit in base 10

Comment: As I said it depends on the problem - it is usually the best method

Comment: what would be a method that would work in all cases? Would Euler's Theorem be useful? So according to Euler's theorem, if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, there will always be an $N=\varphi(b)$ such that $a^N\equiv 1\pmod b.$ So we have $x^y \equiv b \pmod N\Leftrightarrow a^{x^y}\equiv a^b\pmod N.$

Comment: @S. Dolan It's $x^y \equiv c \pmod b$ first and $a^c \equiv \pmod b$. As Simon Fraser said, is there a general mmethod ?

Comment: it's $x^y\equiv c\bmod N \implies a^{x^y}\equiv a^c\bmod b$

Comment: @Moh18, as I mentioned in my above comment, you can use Euler's Theorem if $a$ and $b$ are coprime. If not, then there are two cases: 1) $a$ and $b$ have the same prime factors. In that case, there exists an $N$ such that $a^N\equiv 0\pmod b.$ This $N$ is simply the least common multiple of all the powers of the prime factors of $b.$ This is easy to prove. 2) $a$ and $b$ do not have the same prime factors. Then

Comment: correction: I should've written $x^y \equiv c\pmod N \Leftrightarrow a^{x^y}\equiv a^c\pmod b$

Comment: Also @Moh18 it is very easy to find the last digit of a power. It's the same as the last digit of its units digit raised to the same power. So you just need to find the period of the units digit and take the exponent $x^y$ modulo this period.